# copy the value of ALT field into TITLE field inside <img>

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to copy the individual value of each ALT parameter into a TITLE parameter of the same .
Here is what I have:

html:

```
<div class="images">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="Description 1" title="">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="Description 2" title="">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="Description 3" title="">
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$imagealt = $('.images>img').attr('alt');
$('.images>img').title($imagealt);
```

The result I want to achieve is this:

```
<div class="images">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="Description 1" title="Description 1">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="Description 2" title="Description 2">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="Description 3" title="Description 3">
</div>
```

where title values are dynamically implemented.

I know that this does need a bit advanced code in jquery, than I wrote. It would require a "for-each" implementation. Can you please help me with this? Each image has a specific, different alt parameter value. Thanks

Comment: This is bad for accessibility, please don't do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with your logic is that you're selecting all images at once.

> It would require a "for-each" implementation

Not explicitly. You can use an implicit loop by providing a function to `prop()` which will be executed against each element in turn. This function should then return the new value to set for the property.

```js
$('.images > img').prop('title', function() { return this.alt; });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="Description 1" title="">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="Description 2" title="">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="Description 3" title="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over each of the images, copying the `alt` attribute to the `title` attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.images>img').each(function () {
         $(this).attr('title', $(this).attr('alt'));
    });
})
```